# flutter on ios: how to fill all screen with color

Tags: ios, flutter

I try to fill all mobile screen with dark color. This works well on Android and does not on iOS
I did all this stuff but nothing was changed

```
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        extendBody: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: _MainWidget(),
        bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavBar(),
      ),
    );
```

I still see white color above and below dark one.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the `SafeArea` widget with a colored `Container` like so.

```
Container(
  color: requiredColorHere,
  child: SafeArea(
    // other code
  ),
),
```